# jQuery fadeIn(), fadeOut() cause drastic performance hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, svg

I implemented a loading indicator (an animated .svg) with fadeIn and fadeOut to show/hide it on a page which also has an animated canvas, and there is a considerable drop in performance of my canvas while these operations are occurring, even going so far as to crash a certain mobile browser.

I changed it to simply show() and hide() the element, and there is no problem except it doesn't look quite as nice.

Just wondering if anyone else has noticed such performance issues, and if there is perhaps an alternative way to fade my indicator in/out? Thanks!

Comment: SO isn't an advice forum. Please try rephrasing your question into something more concrete. Opinionated questions get closed. Are you asking how to improve the performance of jQuery fades?

Comment: have you tried css animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery's animation routines are all very "pessimistic" in their implementation. They use timers to explicitly set the opacity in the DOM frame by frame. This causes the browser to force redraws. This is done for historical reasons because CSS transitions didn't always exist and it used to be the only way to achieve these effects.

Now, a more efficient way to let the browser do most of the work using CSS transitions. Rather than letting JQuery do the fading, you simply use it to apply a class. The browser takes care of transitioning between the two states.

Most browsers can accelerate opacity and transform transitions using the GPU.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.fader').addClass('show');
  
  $('.fader').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.fader {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fader">I'll fade in, click me to fade out</div>
```

In the example above, the `setTimeout()` is used to give the DOM a frame to draw up the `<div>` with the `fader` class with an `opacity` of `0`. In the next frame it applies the `show` class which sets the `opacity` to `1`. Because the `transition` is 2 seconds long, it will slowly fade in.

I also added a click event that removes the `show` class and it will slowly fade back out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the alternative, just what I was looking for with my well phrased question. Sadly this method exhibits identical behavior to jQuery.

Comment: Try applying `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to your SVG layer in your CSS. This will force that element to be GPU accelerated. If you just use CSS transforms and opacity, they'll be GPU accelerated and not require re-compositing the way standard fading does.